# UIPageViewController with docking/pinning functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, docking

I've been using UIPageViewController with transitionStyle UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll in order to be able to easily move between views in my app.

I'm looking for a bit more functionality that I won't get from the UIPageViewController so I'm looking to make my own solution - perhaps still a subclass of UIPageViewController.

To explain the extra functionality I'll provide a scenario & a diagram:

[image: Scenario]

In **A** the app is currently showing the first view controller. I then drag from right to left which will of course start to show the second viewcontroller as shown in **B**. If I stop panning before the point where the UIPageViewController decides whether or not to show the second view controller or go back to the first one I'd like it to instead show the second viewcontroller (taking up one third of the screen) instead of hiding it completely.

If I was to keep panning a bit further beyond the halfway point and then released I'd like the second view controller to take up two thirds of the screen, while the first view controller takes up one third.

That's essentially it. I'd appreciate any advice on how to go about doing this. I'm thinking I'll subclass UIPageViewController and override the delegate methods, but I'd really appreciate any advice on a better solution.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could give you a hint or and inspiration. >> 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift